# How to use OpenLayers 5 with Node (express)?

Tags: node.js, express, webpack, openlayers

I've been trying to visualize Vector data. I'm using [Tegola](https://tegola.io/) as vector tile server. My first choice of visualizing library was Leaflet, but Leaflet's [Vector.Grid](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.VectorGrid) library seems to have some problems with point data;

1. [Issue on tegola's Github page.](https://github.com/go-spatial/tegola/issues/469)
2. [Issue on Leaflet.VectorGrid project on Github.](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.VectorGrid/issues/148)

So I've switched to OpenLayers. OpenLayers has a very inclusive library and there are plenty of [examples](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/) and [tutorials](https://openlayers.org/workshop/en/).

It took half a day for me to understand new version and complete the workshop on the link above. OpenLayers seems to be the solution for my needs. But I don't know how to rewrite code the code that I've prepared in workshop which is written to run on web.pack server. I want to render the layers and add a few nodes that will complete my needs on the map.

My map runs on web.pack server ;
[image]

But I want to render this map in Node. So I've write a server file;

```
// Get dependencies
const express = require('express');
const http = require('http');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const dotenv = require('dotenv')
const logger = require('./services/logger');
const cors = require('cors');
const { Pool, Client } = require('pg')
const pool = new Pool()

dotenv.config();
// Get our API routes
const api = require('./routes/api.router');
const client = new Client()
const app = express();


// Parsers for POST data
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cors());

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/script'));
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  // res.sendFile(__dirname + "/views/index.html");
  res.render('index', { title: 'Map' });
});

// Set our api routes
app.use('/api', api);

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  const err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  logger.error(`Request Error ${req.url} - ${err.status}`)
  next(err);
});

app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.json({
    error: {
      message: err.message
    }
  });
});
/**
 * Get port from environment and store in Express.
 */
const port = process.env.PORT || '3000';
app.set('port', port);

const server = http.createServer(app);
server.listen(port, () => console.log(`API running on localhost:${port}`));
```

Confusing part starts from here, I'm using the same HTML file in workshop server(web.pack). But I don't know how to reference main.js file to this HTML file. As you can see below there is no reference to main.js file inside this file.
How does web.pack combines these two files ? And is it possible to the same using express in NodeJS ?

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>OpenLayers</title>
    <style>
        html,
    body,
    #map-container {
      margin: 0;
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
      font-family: sans-serif;
    }

    .arrow_box {
      position: relative;
      background: #000;
      border: 1px solid #003c88;
    }

    .arrow_box:after,
    .arrow_box:before {
      top: 100%;
      left: 50%;
      border: solid transparent;
      content: " ";
      height: 0;
      width: 0;
      position: absolute;
      pointer-events: none;
    }

    .arrow_box:after {
      border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
      border-top-color: #000;
      border-width: 10px;
      margin-left: -10px;
    }

    .arrow_box:before {
      border-color: rgba(0, 60, 136, 0);
      border-top-color: #003c88;
      border-width: 11px;
      margin-left: -11px;
    }

    .arrow_box {
      border-radius: 5px;
      padding: 10px;
      opacity: 0.8;
      background-color: black;
      color: white;
    }

    #popup-content {
      max-height: 200px;
      overflow: auto;
    }

    #popup-content th {
      text-align: left;
      width: 125px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="map-container"></div>
    <div class="arrow_box" id="popup-container">
        <div id="popup-content"></div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

**main.js**

```
import 'ol/ol.css';
import Map from 'ol/Map';
import View from 'ol/View';
import MVT from 'ol/format/MVT';
import VectorTileLayer from 'ol/layer/VectorTile';
import VectorTileSource from 'ol/source/VectorTile';
import TileLayer from 'ol/layer/Tile';
import XYZSource from 'ol/source/XYZ';
import Overlay from 'ol/Overlay';
import { Style, Fill, Stroke, Circle, Text } from 'ol/style';
import { fromLonLat } from 'ol/proj';



const map = new Map({
    target: 'map-container',
    view: new View({
        center: fromLonLat([34.633623, 39.818770]),
        zoom: 7
    })
});

const layer = new VectorTileLayer({
    source: new VectorTileSource({
        attributions: [
            '<a href="http://www.openmaptiles.org/" target="_blank">&copy; OpenMapTiles</a>',
            '<a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/about/" target="_blank">&copy; OpenStreetMap contributors</a>'
        ],
        format: new MVT(),
        url: `http://localhost:8090/maps/observation/{z}/{x}/{y}.vector.pbf`,
        maxZoom: 24,
        type: 'base'
    })
});

const baseLayer = new TileLayer({
    source: new XYZSource({
        url: 'http://tile.stamen.com/terrain/{z}/{x}/{y}.jpg'
    }),
    type: 'base'
});

map.addLayer(baseLayer);

const overlay = new Overlay({
    element: document.getElementById('popup-container'),
    positioning: 'bottom-center',
    offset: [0, -10],
    autoPan: true
});
map.addOverlay(overlay);


overlay.getElement().addEventListener('click', function () {
    overlay.setPosition();
});

map.addLayer(layer);

layer.setStyle(function (feature, resolution) {
    const properties = feature.getProperties();

    if (properties.layer == 'temperature_stations' || properties.layer == 'temperature_stations_simple') {
        const point = new Style({
            image: new Circle({
                radius: 5,
                fill: new Fill({
                    color: 'red'
                }),
                stroke: new Stroke({
                    color: 'grey'
                })
            })
        })
        return point
    }

    if (properties.layer == 'aws_stations') {
        const point = new Style({
            image: new Circle({
                radius: 5,
                fill: new Fill({
                    color: 'blue'
                }),
                stroke: new Stroke({
                    color: 'grey'
                })
            })
        })
        return point
    }

    if (properties.layer == 'spa_stations') {
        const point = new Style({
            image: new Circle({
                radius: 10,
                fill: new Fill({
                    color: 'green'
                }),
                stroke: new Stroke({
                    color: 'grey'
                })
            })
        })
        return point
    }

    if (properties.layer == 'syn_stations') {
        const point = new Style({
            image: new Circle({
                radius: 10,
                fill: new Fill({
                    color: 'purple'
                }),
                stroke: new Stroke({
                    color: 'grey'
                })
            })
        })
        return point
    }

});


map.on('pointermove', function (e) {
    let markup = '';
    map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(e.pixel, function (feature) {
        markup += `${markup && '<hr>'}<table>`;
        const properties = feature.getProperties();
        for (const property in properties) {
            markup += `<tr><th>${property}</th><td>${properties[property]}</td></tr>`;
        }
        markup += '</table>';
    }, { hitTolerance: 0 });
    if (markup) {
        document.getElementById('popup-content').innerHTML = markup;
        overlay.setPosition(e.coordinate);
    } else {
        overlay.setPosition();
    }
});
```

Comment: were you able to solve this issue?

Comment: Yes I did. But couldn’t have the time to post it here.

Comment: can you guide me to your solution?.. :D if you have time

Answer (score 0):

The workshop uses the webpack dev server to serve the application for development. The last chapter explains how to build the application for production: https://openlayers.org/workshop/en/deploying/. The steps explained there explain how to use webpack to give you a static web application, You'll be using the resulting artifacts in your Express application as static files: https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html.

Comment: Hi, I've understand how to use static files. I'm actually looking for a way of using the main.js in Node environment directly. I suppose, to do that, I have to write a code that compiles main.js automatically when I start server in Node.

Comment: That requires a build step, which webpack is used for. And the last chapter of the workflow explains how to do it. See the first link in my answer for more details. When you use webpack's `--watch` option, changes in the client js code will trigger a rebuild and you don't have to run any extra scripts to get the client code updated.